# How do I map relationship fields in Prisma?

Tags: mysql, prisma

This is the user model of my current prisma.scheme:

```prisma
model User{
@@map("users")

ID Int @id @default(autoincrement()) @unique
Firstname String @map("firstname") @db.VarChar(45)
Lastname String @map("lastname") @db.VarChar(45)
Phone String @map("phone") @db.VarChar(60) @unique
EMail String @map("email") @db.VarChar(45) @unique
Username String @map("username") @db.VarChar(45) @unique
Password String @map("password") @db.VarChar(255)
Role Role @map("role") @relation(fields:[Role],references:[ID])
IsLocked Boolean @map("isLocked") @default(false)
Avatar String? @db.VarChar(36) @unique
}
```

For the "Role" column I get the following error:

```
Error parsing attribute "@map": The attribute `@map` cannot be used on relation fields.
```

Is there a way I can map these columns as well?

Answer (score 1):

[`@map` and `@@map`](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/data-model#mapping-model-names-to-tables-or-collections) allow you to name columns and tables differently than what Prisma's default naming convention derives from your field and model names.

You can't use `@map` for relation fields because they do not end up as columns in your database. Providing a custom name with `@map` would not make any sense. You can easily confirm this by having a look into your database with Prisma Studio for example.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this to me.
So this means there is no way to do it like it is possible with typeorm?
In typeorm it was done like this:
https://i.postimg.cc/T3Yz1x7y/image.png